# Can't get MCC Code Configurator to work in MPLAB X

Tags: microchip, mplab

I have freshly installed mplab X v6.05, a code compiler xc32, the harmony config files from Github, and the latest version of Java. I create a new 32bit MCC project and load the MCC tab. I choose Harmony, click finish, and then nothing happens. Except this error message.

> A java.util.concurrent.CompletionException exception has occurred.
> Click Show Details or see the messages.log file located in your C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Roaming\mplab_ide\dev\v6.05\var\log folder.

How can I fix this? I have tried reinstalling everything and restarting the pc.

The device is a pic32mx795, which is supported with Harmony. Same thing happens no matter what device I select though.

[image]

Comment: Try the newest harmony version from www.micrpchip.com. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Click the 'Finish' button to complete the Harmony setup